# Substracting large integers

Tags: c++

I am working on an assignment, but realised an error (C++). For the below code, when I input n = 62, why will the number not be subtracted ?

`long long int total = pow(2,n) - 1`

How should I correctly represent the value ?

I found out that if I do:

```
long long int total = pow(2,n);
long long int final = total - 1
```

It works ? Why ?

Comment: `pow(2,62)` returns a `double`, so `pow(2,62)-1` is also a `double`, which is not exactly representable, so it will be evaluated to the next representable `double`, which is `pow(2,62)`. Powers of 2 are always exactly representable in this format.

Comment: even `2LL << 62` is likely to overflow.

Comment: If so, how should I represent the result ? What should I do if I wanna get pow(2,n) - 1 ? Thanks a lot

Comment: `long long total = (1LL << n) - 1;`